# Selected index changed event of DropDownList fires on every postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have three `DropDownList` with ajax `CascadingDropDown` list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Award" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cas_Award" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddl_Award"
    Category="Award" PromptText="-- Select --" LoadingText="Loading Award..."
    ServicePath="~/WebServices/WebServiceSearch.asmx"  ServiceMethod="GetAward" ContextKey="">
</asp:CascadingDropDown>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_AwardPosition" runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cas_AwardPosition" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddl_AwardPosition"
   Category="AwardPosition" PromptText="-- Select --" LoadingText="Loading Award Position..." 
   ServicePath="~/WebServices/WebServiceSearch.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetAwardPosition" ParentControlID="ddl_Award">
</asp:CascadingDropDown>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_AwardClassification" runat="server"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_AwardClassification_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:CascadingDropDown ID="cas_AwardClassification" runat="server" TargetControlID="ddl_AwardClassification" 
   Category="AwardClassification" PromptText="-- Select --" LoadingText="Loading Award Classification..." 
   ServicePath="~/WebServices/WebServiceSearch.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetAwardClassification" ParentControlID="ddl_AwardPosition">
</asp:CascadingDropDown>
```

`SelectedIndexChanged` event of third `DropDownList` fires on every postback.

How can I prevent this `SelectedIndexChanged` event ?

Comment: pls show page init and page load event's code

Comment: Hi I have figured out that I have not set AutoPostBack="true" in the code earlier. After setting AutoPostBack="true" the problem has been resolved.

Comment: pls post your answer to mark it as resolved.